# Get <html> tag in Angular component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

`<body>` and `<head>` tag can be get in Angular component by injecting`DOCUMENT`, like this:

```js
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject } from '@angular/core';

export class TestComponent {
  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  )

  // get <head>
  // this.document.head

  // get <body>
  // this.document.body
}
```

But is it possible to get `<html>` tag in Angular component?

Comment: And why exactly do you want that?

Comment: `document.documentElement`?

Comment: @SiddAjmera sometimes, class or style may be used on `<html>`. But add these attributes directly on `<html>` in the root `index.html` will take effect globally. Set `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` in specific component to ignore the shadow dom maybe a compromise way, but it will affect all the "none encapusulation" components, which I don't want either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `documentElement` references the *root* element which will be `<html>` in the browser.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/documentElement

```js
@Component({..})
public class ExampleComponent {
   public constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) doc: Document) {
      console.log(doc.documentElement);
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to change your console.log to reference the injected doc instead of the global variable. Otherwise, it looks good